# first in c++ program don't compile and execute

Tags: programming, c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
          cout << " hello world !! good job nothing & something" << "\n" ; 
          cout << " i jitendra singh in first c++";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pure programming questions unrelated to Ubuntu are off topic here. If the program doesn't compile, the compiler should give some helpful output. I don't see any syntax errors here. Please add the compiler output as an [edit] to your question, so it can be determined whether this question is off-topic or not.

Answer (score 2):

General question, general answer:

The code works and can be compiled:

```
g++ foo.cpp
./a.out
```

Output:

```
 hello world !! good job nothing & something
 i jitendra singh in first c++%
```

Your code in `foo.cpp`:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
          cout << " hello world !! good job nothing & something" << "\n" ; 
          cout << " i jitendra singh in first c++";


    return 0;
}
```